# List Objects in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, list, object

Which one is the correct JSON syntax for List of Objects ?
I have seen different implementation at different sources.

```
{
  "Employees": [
        {
          "name": "foo",
          "age": 23
        },
        {
          "name": "bar",
          "age": 37
        }
      ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "employees": [
        {
          "employee": {
            "name": "foo",
            "age": 23
          }
        },
        {
          "employee": {
            "name": "bar",
            "age": 37
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: I think the first is more standard, but it's just a matter of convention; they're both technically valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer the first one for your data type.

```
{
  "Employees": [
        {
          "name": "foo",
          "age": 23
        },
        {
          "name": "bar",
          "age": 37
        }
      ]
}
```

Lets say you want to retrieve an employee.

```
var firstEmployee = Employees[0]
```

Seems logical.